# When is Wade "Deadpool" Wilson's birthday?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

Wade Wilson, AKA Deadpool, doesn't have his birthday listed in any [[1](http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_%28Wade_Wilson%29)] of the wikis [[2](http://deadpool.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool)].

Was it ever disclosed?

Comment: Maybe someone could ask Rob Liefeld?

Comment: Wiki here says his DOB is 22nd November 1978 (https://marveldcfanfiction.fandom.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson)

Answer (score 5):

It has never been explicitly stated. Most writers will tend to avoid specific DOBs to allow their character's age to remain ambiguous or unchanging. Even the DOB of ageless characters, such as Wolverine, are kept deliberately vague. Establishing a concrete date can screw with the continuity. Especially once the comic series (or any other form of media) runs for more than a few years.

Comment: But surely people can omit the year part, right?

Answer (score -1):

it has been said in a french comic it is 3/4/1978

Comment: Which French comic? Can you provide a more specific source?

Comment: On top of what Rand has said why should we assume this French comic has canon information on Wade's birthday?

Comment: On top of that, is the date in US or French format? I.e is it April 3rd or March 4th?

Answer (score -5):

Deadpool's date of birth is: 11/22/1973

Comment: Hi there. What's your source? Could you [edit] it in?

Comment: It's SLIGHTLY suspicious that the date you gave is today's date, minus 25 years...

Comment: @K-H-W super necro reply, but your maths is AWFUL

Comment: This is kinda weird, but I guess user107447 is right. Its the same date in DP's wiki page. However, can Wiki be completely trustworthy?

Comment: @GordonBennett -- 25, 45.. yeah, yeah...  Didn't notice my typo :)